# What chipset does this device have?

Tags: usb, drivers

I have a Freecom DVB-T Art No: 25452

I know the revision 4 of this device runs a Realtek chipset, but I think this one has a different one but a Google search gives me conflicting information

Its VID is 14aa and PID is 022a

Thanks

Comment: Does it list any drivers when you plug it in? Which OS are you using? Linux and FreeBSD might help with *lsusb* windows is a bit more clock work.

Comment: Windows 7 states that a driver cannot be found. As per title, I want to find the chipset, not just a driver. Thanks

Comment: Windows lists the device ID information even if no driver can be found. For that you have to go to the device manager, select the unknow device, right click for properties. The right most tab 'details' defaults to 'device description', but you can also use the drop down box to display the 'Hardware IDs'.  That ID might be the chipset (might since I know it works for PCIe devices but I never tested it with USB).

Comment: The IDs from that option are in my OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices) (waaay down page) it looks like it's based on the ZL353 chipset, natively supported in the linux kernel. (but you're not using linux)

Have you tried going to the manufacturer's website for drivers?

Going to the [freecom.com](http://freecom.com) website, product support, downloads & faq's..., several drivers available, one matching your given article 25452 for vista, which should work with Windows 7.  [Direct Link](http://www.freecom.com/files/Productinformation/EOL/DVBT/Driver/25452-XP-32-Vista-3264.zip) to driver download.

To recap, since the answer above might be lost in the noise:

Chipset is ZL353.